# Laravel with Eloquent doesn't save model properties on database

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm buiding an web app using php laravel framework. When I save the model on the database it makes an insert but doesn't save model properties. I can't see how to fix because the laravel log doesn't show any mistake. Any idea?

There's the model:

```
/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'test';
//  protected $fillable = array('name', 'surname', 'mobile', 'phone', 'mail', 'adress');

// Model properties
private $name;
private $surname;
private $mobile;
private $phone;
private $mail;
private $adress;

// Model constructor
function __construct($name, $surname, $mobile, $phone, $mail, $adress) {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->surname = $surname;
    $this->mobile = $mobile;
    $this->phone = $phone;
    $this->mail = $mail;
    $this->adress = $adress;
}
```

And there's php code which create User object and save it to the database

```
<?php

// Create an object using model's constructor
$user = new User('John', 'Doe', 685412578, 9354784125, 'j@doe.com', 'Portland');

// Show some properties
echo '<p>'.$user->getName().'</p>';
echo '<p>'.$user->getSurname().'</p>';

// Saving model on database
$user->save();

?>
```

When I execute the php code show on screen the model properties and makes an insert but doesn't save the properties. Would be great if someone can help me :)

---

There's is the solution (if someone has the same problem or similar)

Model:

```
    protected $table = 'test';

    // Fields on databse to save model properties
    protected $fillable = array('name', 'surname', 'mobile', 'phone', 'mail', 'adress');

    // Model properties
    private $name;
    private $surname;
    private $mobile;
    private $phone;
    private $mail;
    private $adress;
```

And php code:

```
 <?php

        // Create an object
                    $user = User::create(array(
                        'name'=>'John', 
                        'surname'=>'Doe', 
                        'mobile'=>685412578, 
                        'phone'=>9354784125, 
                        'mail'=>'j@doe.com', 
                        'adress'=>'Portland'
                        ));

        // Show some properties
        echo '<p>'.$user->name.'</p>';
        echo '<p>'.$user->surname.'</p>';

        // Saving model on database
        $user->save();

    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you lowerends and watcher both are right, now is working. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described at http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment, you need the `$fillable` property set for all the properties you want to be mass-assignable. You should therefore uncomment the line starting with `protected $fillable = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the column names that you're storing for the particular model in the model itself.  One of the purposes of the ORM is to remove this responsibility from you.  What you have also obviously won't work because Eloquent's getters / setters are specified in a parent class, yet you have the properties themselves defined as `private` which is inaccessible from any parent / child scope.

My suggestion: completely remove these lines from your model:

```
private $name;
private $surname;
private $mobile;
private $phone;
private $mail;
private $adress;
```

Remove your constructor in there as well.  If you want to create an instance and store it in the database, you can do this:

```
$user = User::create(array(
    'name' => 'John',
    'surname' => 'Doe',
    // ... etc
));
```

And later you can easily access the properties of this instance:

```
echo $user->name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify these in the constructor.  You can use `mass-assignment`.

**Model:**

```
class User extends Eloquent {

protected $fillable = ['name', 'suname', 'mobile', 'phone', 'mail', 'address'];

}
```

**Controller:**

```
$user = new User(['name' => 'John', 'surname' => 'Doe', 'mobile' => '685412578', 'phone' => '9354784125','mail' => 'j@doe.com', 'address' => 'Portland']);

$user->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Eloquent` class that your models extend can't reach the properties because you're declaring them as `private`. You can either not directly specify the properties on the model, or you can declare them as either `protected` or `public`, then Eloquent will have access to them and be able to save them to your database.

Answer (score 0):

```
class User extends Model {

    protected $table = 'users';

    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.