# PHP Laravel save model properties via constructor

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to simply save a model to the database via a controller without setting the fields directly but instead having them set in the constructor of said object.

Here is the class handling the logic. If the commented out line

`//$todoItem->item = $todo;` is uncommented, it works fine and saves whatever is entered in $todo in the database. However, I would like to set that value in the constructor of the task object and not need to manually specify it. I found this question: [Laravel with Eloquent doesn't save model properties on database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25773441/laravel-with-eloquent-doesnt-save-model-properties-on-database) suggesting I could set the property as protected and have it work, but that still does not.

`NewTodo.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class NewTodo extends Controller
{

    public function saveTodoItem(Request $request)
    {

        $todo = $request->input('content');
        $todoItem = new \App\Task($todo);
        //$todoItem->item = $todo;
        $todoItem->save();

        return view('testview', ['name' => $todoItem->getItem()]);
    }
}
```

`Task.php`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{
    protected $item = null;

    function __construct($newItem)
    {
        $this->item = $newItem; 
    }

    function getItem()
    {
        return $this->item;
    }


}
```

Summary, database entry being stored as blank unless $todo->item is manually set when from what I can $todo->item is being set in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify these in the constructor. You can use [Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment)

**Model:**

```
class Task extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['item'];
}
```

**Controller:**

```
class NewTodo extends Controller
{

    public function saveTodoItem(Request $request)
    {

        $todo = $request->input('content');
        $todoItem = new \App\Task::create(['item' => $todo]);

        return view('testview', ['name' => $todoItem->getItem()]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated. Thanks and will accept in 4 minutes.